# Python SQLite3 AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Tags: python, sqlite3

При написании небольшой программы для контроля базы данных на SQLite3 и PyWebIO возникает данная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywebio\session\coroutinebased.py", line 321, in step
    coro_yield = self.coro.send(result)
  File "C:\Users\WORK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywebio\session\coroutinebased.py", line 101, in _start_main_task
    await target()
  File "C:\Users\WORK\Desktop\SQLite\main.py", line 20, in main
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ('id' INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'name' STRING)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

Вот код:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

import asyncio

from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import defer_call, info as session_info

global name
name = ""
async def main():
    put_markdown("Users database control.")
    database = put_scope(name="database")
    put_scrollable(database, height=300, keep_bottom=True)
    
    with sql.connect('Users.db') as db:

        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ('id' INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'name' STRING)")
        def add():
            global name
            cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users")
            cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users ('name') VALUES (?)",(name))
            clear("database")
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            [put_text(f'{row[0]}    {row[1]}', scope="database") for row in rows]
            toast(f"Sucessfully added {name}")

        def delete():
            global name
            cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users")
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?",(name))
            clear("database")
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            [put_text(f'{row[0]}    {row[1]}', scope="database") for row in rows]
            toast(f"Sucessfully deleted {name}")
            
        def exit():
            toast("See you next time!")
            db.commit()
            cursor.close()
            quit()
        def clr():
            global next_id
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users")
            next_id = 0
            toast("Sucessfully cleared database")
            clear("database")
        global name
        put_button("Add user", onclick=add)
        put_button("Delete user", onclick=delete)
        put_button("Clear database", onclick=clr)
        put_button("Exit", onclick=exit)
        while True:
            clear("database")
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS")
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            [put_text(f'{row[0]}    {row[1]}', scope="database") for row in rows]
            name = await input("Username", placeholder="Username")
        put_button("Exit", onclick=exit)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server(main, port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опечатка в Слове "Integer".
Вот корректный запрос:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'name' STRING)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло